# What is the earliest map of Washington, D.C.?

Tags: united-states, maps, reference

What is the earliest official map of Washington, D.C. and where can it be found in the digital form and highest possible resolution? Googling didn't yield a credible answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The earliest map was the L'Enfant Plan, made before the city existed.

[image]

Here is a [collection](http://www.historicmapworks.com/Browse/United_States/District+of+Columbia/) of all the important city maps, going back to 1792.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I appreciate it a lot. Is there a chance I can get my hands on this particular original scan without any paywalls?

Comment: Never mind about the scan request, "Search Google for image" is a wonderful thing.

Comment: Very "unconfusing City" ... laid out in a similar way to NY City as almost everything comes at right angles with a few notable exceptions. I think it burned down and had to be rebuilt ... by memory of an African American is my memory serves me right. Always meant to be built using stone and even today no building within the District can be higher than the Capitol Dome.